# Multiple File upload storing only last file in database Asp .Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to upload multiple files. The files are getting uploaded correctly but in the database, only the last file is stored
This is my code for the post method

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> ApplyLeave(ApplyLeaveViewModel model)
        {

            string uniqueFileName = null;
            if (model.File != null && model.File.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (IFormFile file in model.File)
                {
                    string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "dist/files");
                    uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.FileName;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                    file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                }

                var leaveApplied = _mapper.Map<LeaveViewModel>(model);
                leaveApplied.FilePath = uniqueFileName;
                await _leavePageService.AddNewLeave(leaveApplied);
             
              
            }

            return View(model);
        }    }
```

This the part of ApplyLeaveViewModel corresponding to leave the property

```
        public string Reason { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public List<IFormFile> File { get; set; }
```

This the LeaveViewModel which is getting mapped and storing the data in the database

```
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
```

I understand that uniqueFileName is a string which is storing only one value at a time, so it displays the last value. What should I do, so that all the uploaded files are stored in the database

Comment: You're calling `AddNewLeave` outside your foreach loop.

Comment: I tried AddNewLeave inside the foreach loop , but it still gives the same result

Comment: Can you give the code for **AddNewLeave**? Is it a method used to store data in a database? Also, can you tell me the type of **leaveApplied**?

Comment: @Yihui Sun Basically AddNewLeave is method which uses the inbuilt AddAsync method. It is getting mapped between Leave(which the the core entity) , LeaveModel and then LeaveViewModel . So this is the addAsync method 
`public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
        {
            _manageContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            await _manageContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }
`
        
leaveApplied is of type LeaveViewModel
if File1 and File2 are uploaded only File2 is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that uniqueFileName is a string which is storing only one value at a time, so it displays the last value.

You get the **uniqueFileName** after `foreach (IFormFile file in model.File)` ends, so its value is the **name of the last file**.

1. **The first solution** is that you do **not change your Model**, that is, use `public string FilePath {get; set;}` to **store the uniqueFileName of multiple files**.

   1. You need to concatenate all the uniqueFileNames, and separate the uniqueFileNames with a character (such as |).

      - ```
          string allfilesPath = null;
          if (model.File != null && model.File.Count > 0)
          {
              foreach (IFormFile file in model.File)
              {
                  ... ...
                  allfilesPath += "|" + uniqueFileName;
              }
              var leaveApplied = _mapper.Map<LeaveModel>(model);
              leaveApplied.AllFiles = allfilesPath;
        ```
   2. When you get the value next time, you need to use **String.Split Method** to **split the string** to get each uniqueFileName.
2. The **second solution** is: you can **add a new Model** called **FileModel**, which is used to store file information, and you can **set the navigation properties** to make **LeaveModel and FileModel** have a **one-to-many relationship**.

   1. I wrote an example, you can refer to it.
   2. **Model**

      ```
       public class LeaveModel
       {
           [Key]
           public int LeaveId { get; set; }
           public string Reason { get; set; }
           public string Comment { get; set; }
           public List<FileModel> AllFiles { get; set; }
       }
       public class FileModel
       {
           [Key]
           public int FileId { get; set; }
           public string FilePath { get; set; }
           public int? LeaveId { get; set; }
       }
       public class ApplyLeaveViewModel
       {
           public string Reason { get; set; }
           public string Comment { get; set; }
           public List<IFormFile> File { get; set; }
       }
      ```
   3. **LeaveController**

      ```
       public class LeaveController : Controller
       {
           public IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
           private readonly IMapper _mapper;
           public DailyCoreMVCDemoContext _db;
           public LeaveController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IMapper mapper, DailyCoreMVCDemoContext db)
           {
               _mapper = mapper;
               _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
               _db = db;
           }
           public IActionResult Index()
           {
               return View();
           }
           public IActionResult ApplyLeave(ApplyLeaveViewModel model)
           {
               string uniqueFileName = null;
               if (model.File != null && model.File.Count > 0)
               {
                   List<FileModel> fileModels = new List<FileModel>();
                   foreach (IFormFile file in model.File)
                   {
                       string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "dist/files");
                       if (!Directory.Exists(uploadsFolder))
                       {
                           Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadsFolder);
                       }
                       uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.FileName;
                       string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                       file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                       fileModels.Add(new FileModel { FilePath = uniqueFileName });
                   }
                   var leaveApplied = _mapper.Map<LeaveModel>(model);
                   leaveApplied.AllFiles = fileModels;
                   _db.LeaveModels.Add(leaveApplied);
                   _db.SaveChanges();
               }
               return RedirectToAction("Index");
           }
       }
      ```
   4. **Index**

      ```
       @model WebApplication24.Models.ApplyLeaveViewModel
       <form asp-controller="Leave" asp-action="ApplyLeave" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input asp-for="Comment"/>
       <input asp-for="Reason"/>
       <input asp-for="File" type="file" multiple/>
           <button type="submit">submit</button>
       </form>
      ```
   5. **Result**

      [image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Really appreciate the effort. For now i just separated them with a comma, but will implement the proper one soon. Thanks one again